# Is Nidoran♂ or Nidoran♀ more common in FireRed/LeafGreen?

Tags: pokemon-fire-red-leaf-green

Serebii.net's [guide for FireRed/LeafGreen in-game trades](http://serebii.net/fireredleafgreen/trades.shtml) says the following about the Nidoran trade on Route 5:

> The underground tunnel (north exit) has a trainer who will trade Nidoran for Nidoran. Whichever the rarer Nidoran is in your version is what's offered.

However, which Nidoran is rarer is not listed. Is Nidoran♂ or Nidoran♀ more common in FireRed/LeafGreen?

Comment: I'm sad to see that this was downvoted. It seemed like a good question to ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Serebii lists [Nidoran♀](http://www.serebii.net/pokedex-rs/029.shtml) to be rare in FireRed, and [Nidoran♂](http://www.serebii.net/pokedex-rs/032.shtml) to be rare in LeafGreen.